# Noscript form fallback for no javascript browser

Tags: javascript, html, forms, noscript, client-side-scripting

I am coding a landingpage for one of our future products and I have a little trouble with that

> ```
>     <form novalidate method="POST" class="subscribe-form">
>     <noscript>
>       </form>
>       <form method="POST" action="/" class="subscribe-form">
>     </noscript>
>       <input type="email" placeholder="{subscribe-status}" class="input-lg" name="email">
>       <input type="text" value="general" class="hidden" name="interest" class="interest-field">
>       <input type="submit" value="Let me know!" class="btn btn-blue btn-lg" data-location="header">
>     </form>
>     <span class="hint">*Prepare to be amazed. We promise we won't spam you.</span>
> ```

The idea is to have defined form for js supporting browser and be ready for client side validation, but in case of noscript browser to have a fallback ready. But chrome renders it like that [image: chrome-render]

Any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers have different behavior how to render the DOM

one option is to turn on/off the noValidate with javascript

```
<form id="myForm" novalidate method="POST" class="subscribe-form">
    <script> document.getElementById("myForm").noValidate = true; </script>
    <input type="email" placeholder="{subscribe-status}" class="input-lg" name="email">
    <input type="text" value="general" class="hidden" name="interest" class="interest-field">
    <input type="submit" value="Let me know!" class="btn btn-blue btn-lg" data-location="header">
</form>
<span class="hint">*Prepare to be amazed. We promise we won't spam you.</span>
```

Another is to to toggle the visibility of js/no-js elements with css

```
<style>
    .myclass { 
        /* CSS code for all versions of your page goes here */
    }

    .js .myclass {
        /* This CSS code will only show up if JS is enabled */
    } 

    .no-js .myclass {
        /* This CSS code will only show up if JS is disabled. */
    }
</style>

<script>
    // Remove "no-js" class from <html> element, if it exists:
    var docElement = document.documentElement;
    docElement.className = docElement.className.replace("no-js", "js");
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The HTML is not valid; different browsers are likely to render it differently.  The W3C validator is your friend: http://validator.w3.org/

If JS is turned off, your validation won't run, and you don't really need to do anything about that; just write one form and use it for both cases.  If you need/want to know server-side whether the client side validation has been run, include `<input type="hidden" name="clientvalidated" value="false">` in your form and change the value attribute to true with JS.

Note that you *must* validate at the server anyway because the client is untrusted.

Answer (score 0):

This wont work because incase you have javascript disabled it will generate 3 tags ( and

Merging 2 forms in one which is not very clean and can have unwanted sideeffects.

I would suggest you do it otherwise, create 2 complete forms mark them with an ID. The JavaScript version should be hidden by default. Then JavaScript should perform the changes that are nesessary only if JavaScript works.

```
<form id="this_is_for_javascript_mode" method="post" style="display: none;">
    -put form content here...-
</form>

<form id="this_is_for_non_javascript_mode" method="post">
    -put form content here...-
</form>
```

And then simply control visiblity by JavaScript.

This will work because a script-tag will not be executed if JavaScript id disabled in the browser!

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    $("#this_is_for_non_javascript_mode").remove(); //Remove non-js version
    $("#this_is_for_javascript_mode").css("display", "block"); //Make js version visible
</script>
```